# Dial multiple IP addresses with golang gRPC client

Tags: go, grpc

I have grpc server `192.168.1.12:8800` and `192.168.1.13:8800`, I want to connect them use `grpc.Dial` with ip list, not server discover, How can I do?

```
conn, err = grpc.Dial("192.168.1.12:8800,192.168.1.13:8800", grpc.WithInsecure())
```

with error

```
rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: too many colons in address 192.168.1.12:8800,192.168.1.13:8800
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you encounter? Include your code, and any output or errors you received.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, you aren't able to pass multiple IP addresses using `grpc.Dial(...)`, it only takes a single argument.

gRPC in Go does have an ["experimental" load balancer](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/balancer) api that you should be able to take advantage of.

An example of the resolver you would need to write can be found [here](https://github.com/hakobe/grpc-go-client-side-load-balancing-example/blob/master/client/resolver.go). It creates a fake resolver that will load balance across the multiple IP addresses.

So once you have a resolver such as that, the code you would want would look something like this:

```
conn, err := grpc.Dial(
    "",
    grpc.WithInsecure(),
    grpc.WithBalancer(grpc.RoundRobin(resolver.NewPseudoResolver([]string{
        "10.0.0.1:10000",
        "10.0.0.2:10000",
    }))),
)
```

Comment: That's actually what I need! Lifetime-saver answer !

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a library for this: https://github.com/Jille/grpc-multi-resolver

Usage is easy:

```golang
import _ "github.com/Jille/grpc-multi-resolver"

grpc.Dial("multi:///192.168.1.12:8800,192.168.1.13:8800")
```

Note the triple slash at the beginning.

Comment: This is outdated.. does not work

Comment: @ArpitPruthi Updated and fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented this kind of gRPC resolver in https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder:

`resolver` implementation:

```golang
package grpc

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "strings"

    "google.golang.org/grpc/resolver"
)

// staticBuilder implements the `resolver.Builder` interface.
type staticBuilder struct{}

// newStaticBuilder creates a `staticBuilder` used to construct static DNS
// resolvers.
func newStaticBuilder() resolver.Builder {
    return &staticBuilder{}
}

// Build implements the `resolver.Builder` interface and is usually called by
// the gRPC dialer. It takes a target containing a comma separated list of
// IPv4/6 addresses and a `resolver.ClientConn` and returns a `staticResolver`
// which implements the `resolver.Resolver` interface.
func (sb *staticBuilder) Build(target resolver.Target, cc resolver.ClientConn, _ resolver.BuildOptions) (resolver.Resolver, error) {
    var resolverAddrs []resolver.Address
    for _, address := range strings.Split(target.Endpoint, ",") {
        parsedAddress, err := parseResolverIPAddress(address)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        resolverAddrs = append(resolverAddrs, *parsedAddress)
    }
    return newStaticResolver(cc, resolverAddrs), nil
}

// Scheme returns the scheme that `staticBuilder` will be registered for, for
// example: `static:///`.
func (sb *staticBuilder) Scheme() string {
    return "static"
}

// staticResolver is used to wrap an inner `resolver.ClientConn` and implements
// the `resolver.Resolver` interface.
type staticResolver struct {
    cc resolver.ClientConn
}

// newStaticResolver takes a `resolver.ClientConn` and a list of
// `resolver.Addresses`. It updates the state of the `resolver.ClientConn` with
// the provided addresses and returns a `staticResolver` which wraps the
// `resolver.ClientConn` and implements the `resolver.Resolver` interface.
func newStaticResolver(cc resolver.ClientConn, resolverAddrs []resolver.Address) resolver.Resolver {
    cc.UpdateState(resolver.State{Addresses: resolverAddrs})
    return &staticResolver{cc: cc}
}

// ResolveNow is a no-op necessary for `staticResolver` to implement the
// `resolver.Resolver` interface. This resolver is constructed once by
// staticBuilder.Build and the state of the inner `resolver.ClientConn` is never
// updated.
func (sr *staticResolver) ResolveNow(_ resolver.ResolveNowOptions) {}

// Close is a no-op necessary for `staticResolver` to implement the
// `resolver.Resolver` interface.
func (sr *staticResolver) Close() {}

// parseResolverIPAddress takes an IPv4/6 address (ip:port, [ip]:port, or :port)
// and returns a properly formatted `resolver.Address` object. The `Addr` and
// `ServerName` fields of the returned `resolver.Address` will both be set to
// host:port or [host]:port if the host is an IPv6 address.
func parseResolverIPAddress(addr string) (*resolver.Address, error) {
    host, port, err := net.SplitHostPort(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("splitting host and port for address %q: %w", addr, err)
    }
    if port == "" {
        // If the port field is empty the address ends with colon (e.g.
        // "[::1]:").
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("address %q missing port after port-separator colon", addr)
    }
    if host == "" {
        // Address only has a port (i.e ipv4-host:port, [ipv6-host]:port,
        // host-name:port). Keep consistent with net.Dial(); if the host is
        // empty (e.g. :80), the local system is assumed.
        host = "127.0.0.1"
    }
    if net.ParseIP(host) == nil {
        // Host is a DNS name or an IPv6 address without brackets.
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("address %q is not an IP address", addr)
    }
    parsedAddr := net.JoinHostPort(host, port)
    return &resolver.Address{
        Addr:       parsedAddr,
        ServerName: parsedAddr,
    }, nil
}

// init registers the `staticBuilder` with the gRPC resolver registry.
func init() {
    resolver.Register(newStaticBuilder())
}
```

Usage example:

```golang
    return grpc.Dial(
        "static:///192.168.1.12:8800,192.168.1.13:8800",
        grpc.WithBalancerName("round_robin"),
    )
```